# ArgumentError: An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to , cc, or bcc address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I got an rails 4 application with following mailer configuration:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'myhost.com' }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address            => 'smtp.myhost.com',
    :port               => 587,
    :domain             => 'myhost.com',
    :authentication     => :login,
    :enable_starttls_auto => false,
    :tls                  => false,
    :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none',
    :ssl => false,
    :user_name          => "myusername",
    :password           => "mypassword"
  }
```

Every time i try to send an mail with an testing mailer setup:

```
class TestMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default :from => "noreply@myhost.com"

  def welcome_email
    mail(:to => "testmail@mymailaddress.com", :subject => "Test mail", :body => "Test mail body")
  end
end

TestMailer.welcome_email.deliver
```

I got this exception:

> ArgumentError: An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set
>   the message smtp_envelope_to, to , cc, or bcc address.

Is it possible that i forget something to set.?
And i can't find an configuration option for "smtp_envelope_to"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The error message is not about the SMTP envelope, but about the sender:

> An SMTP To address is required to send a message

the rest is just a generic message.
Something in your `testmail@mymailaddress.com` is not working. 
Do you use a real, working address? If not, try with one.

Comment: Thx my failure was an overriding of an smtp address wich set it to nil Oo

Answer (score 5):

If you use sidekiq+actionmailer. Be careful, while sending email using hash. I was doing something like this
MyWorker.perform_async("var1", {email: 'test@test.com', var2: 'test1234'})

I banged my head for couple of hours, why it is throwing the above error. Because in the perform_menthod hash[:email] is nil. You need to use hash["email"] to receive the email. I do not know, the reason. But it helped me to get rid of this error.

Comment: Maybe sorry for offtopic, but the reason why you have to use hash['email'] is thanks to serialization process into redis. Sidekiq creates JSON document, it automatically converts all keys to strings.

Answer (score 2):

Is `:to => 'testmail@mymailaddress.com'` how it is in your failing environment? If it's not a hardcoded email address, do make sure that a variable containing the to-address is not blank.

You don't have to set `Mail::Message#smtp_envelope_to` explicitly. It can guess it from its recipients, ie. `Mail::Message#destinations` (to + cc + bcc), but it doesn't seem to have any.

Comment: Simple suggestion and exactly what fixed my problem. My APP_CONFIG value passed in my SMTP `default from:` was returning `nil`.