# Jobs are failing due to SMTP connection in sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am using `sidekiq`

In production i have around 100 jobs to process each day with a queue of 2000 jobs.

I found most of the time the jobs are failing due to SMTP connection.

The Errors I am getting in with sidekiq failures are

```
ArgumentError: An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.
Processor: mysite:17289


Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 435 Unable to authenticate at present
Processor: mysite:17289
```

But most of the jobs are processing successfully in same SMTP connections.

Also I have set the retry conditions as

```
sidekiq_options retry: 5

  sidekiq_retry_in do |count|
    10 * (count + 1) # (i.e. 10, 20, 30, 40)
  end
```

What may be the reason ? Can anybody guess?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

*THis is my AdvertisementWorker*

```
class AdvertisementWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker
  #sidekiq_options queue: "high"
  sidekiq_options retry: 5

  sidekiq_retry_in do |count|
    10 * (count + 1) # (i.e. 10, 20, 30, 40)
  end

  def perform(advertisement_id)

    advertisement = Advertisement.find_by_id(advertisement_id)
    cost = advertisement.is_reactivation_chargable? ? advertisement.ad_type.value : ZERO_COST
    timezone = advertisement.user.timezone.nil? ? DEFAULT_TIMEZONE : advertisement.user.timezone
    schedule_time_def = advertisement.expire_at.nil? ? 0 : ((advertisement.expire_at.in_time_zone(timezone) - Time.now.in_time_zone(timezone))/1.hour).round

    unless schedule_time_def >= 6
      advertisement.expire!
      UserMailer.send_ad_expired_email(advertisement).deliver  if advertisement.is_ad_expiry_notifiable?
      if advertisement.can_auto_renew?
        if advertisement.reactivate!
          advertisement.remove_token_charge(cost) if cost.to_i > 0
          UserMailer.send_seller_ad_reposted_email(advertisement).deliver  if advertisement.is_ad_renew_notifiable?
          advertisement.schedule_sidekiq_job
        end
      end
    end

  end

end
```

**EDIT**

*This is the sidekiq log*

```
2014-05-19T05:14:26Z 20682 TID-9z4kc Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer JID-8e5eeba2afd077ccbca10646 INFO: start
2014-05-19T05:14:26Z 20682 TID-9z4kc Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer JID-8e5eeba2afd077ccbca10646 INFO: fail: 0.012 sec
2014-05-19T05:14:26Z 20682 TID-9z4kc WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer", "args"=>["---\n- !ruby/class 'UserMailer'\n- :send_seller_ad_reposted_email\n- - !ruby/object:Advertisement\n    attributes:\n      id: 1781\n      user_id: 99\n      status: A\n      custom_id: \n      title: Possible Male Crested Gecko Cn37\n      details: |\n        <p>*Red and Yellow Harlequin!* Approximate hatch: 10/2013</p>\n\n        <p>Possible Male (some visible pores)</p>\n\n        <p>Weight: 8 grams</p>\n\n        <p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n        <p><a href=\"http://www.pangeareptile.com/store/new-possible-male-crested-gecko-0417-cn37.html\"><span style=\"font-size:20px\"><strong>PURCHASE HERE</strong></span></a></p>\n      keywords: Red Yellow Crested Gecko for sale Pangea\n      published_at: \n      ad_duration: 30\n      is_renewed: true\n      renewed_till: \n      is_ad_expired_notification: false\n      category_id: 141\n      sex: unknown\n      weight: \n      is_bin: false\n      paypal_account: \n      total_quantity: 0\n      remaining_quantity: 0\n      is_multiple_buy: false\n      item_price: 0.0\n      shipping_handling_price: 0.0\n      comment: \n      blocked: \n      ad_signature: \n      created_at: 2014-04-18 18:59:18.712041000 Z\n      updated_at: 2014-05-19 04:49:56.682501024 Z\n      ad_type: \n      will_trade: false\n      no_bin_price_type: ''\n      no_bin_price: 299.99\n      publish_time: \n      ad_type_id: 3\n      activation_date: 2014-05-19 04:49:56.680462283 Z\n      views: 1\n      expire_at: 2014-06-18 04:49:56.680462283 Z\n      renewed_times: 1\n      renewed_at: 2014-05-19 04:49:56.680514387 Z\n      sold: 0\n      upgrade_type_id: 3\n      expire_mail_sent: false\n      check_signature: \n      scheduled_admin: false\n      hold: 0\n      job_id: 3083e6f7d252cbe309c0709f\n"], "jid"=>"8e5eeba2afd077ccbca10646", "enqueued_at"=>1400474996.731637, "error_message"=>"An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.", "error_class"=>"ArgumentError", "failed_at"=>1400476466.3814178, "retry_count"=>6, "retried_at"=>1400476466.381097, "processor"=>"marketplace.thereptilereport.com:20682"}
2014-05-19T05:14:26Z 20682 TID-9z4kc WARN: An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.
2014-05-19T05:14:26Z 20682 TID-9z4kc WARN: /var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:9:in `check_delivery_params'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:98:in `deliver!'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in `do_delivery'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `block in deliver'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:456:in `block in deliver_mail'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:454:in `deliver_mail'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `deliver'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/extensions/action_mailer.rb:20:in `perform'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:122:in `call'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:122:in `block in invoke'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124:in `block in invoke'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:62:in `call'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124:in `block in invoke'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-failures-0.4.1/lib/sidekiq/failures/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124:in `block in invoke'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `block in call'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:22:in `with_context'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in `call'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124:in `block in invoke'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `call'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `invoke'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:49:in `block in process'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:92:in `stats'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:48:in `process'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `public_send'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `dispatch'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:122:in `dispatch'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:322:in `block in handle_message'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:416:in `block in task'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:55:in `block in initialize'
/var/www/trrm_prod/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:13:in `block in create'
```

Answer (score 2):

There's this:
[ArgumentError: An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to , cc, or bcc address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419611/argumenterror-an-smtp-to-address-is-required-to-send-a-message-set-the-message)

Post your actual code.  You might have a thread-safety issue in your code.

Comment: Please review my AdvertisementWorker in EDIT section of the question. Which code do you need to review? Which file/files I need to show you please specify.